# How to inherit the PHAsset class and add attributes

Tags: ios, swift

AssetGridModel Inherit the PHAsset class and add the isSelected property

```
fileprivate var fetchResult: [AssetGridModel]!

let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        let fetchAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
```

or

```
 let fetchAssets = AssetGridModel.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
```

Why I have come out of the type are PHAsset, not I wrote the inheritance class and can not change the attributes I added?

Please advise me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use runtime solve it

```
extension PHAsset {

    struct RuntimeKey {
        static var isSelectedKey = UnsafeRawPointer.init(bitPattern: "isSelectedKey".hashValue)
    }

    var isSelectedImage: Bool? {
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, PHAsset.RuntimeKey.isSelectedKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC)
        }
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, PHAsset.RuntimeKey.isSelectedKey) as? Bool
        }
    }
}
```